# MS Excel - Sum of one column based on repeating values from another column

Tags: excel-formula, formula

I have been trying to figure out a formula that will calculate the sum of multiple entries above it in the column but only based on the value from another column. For example:

```
 Unit         Card Brand                     Uncaptured Amount

 7804         MasterCard Deposit             7.89
 7804         Visa Deposit                   15.65
 7804         Visa Deposit                   14.55
 7804         Visa Deposit                   20.69
 7804         Visa Deposit                   11.69
 *Total for 7804*                              x
 904          Visa Deposit                   1.68
 904          Visa Deposit                   14.28
 *Total for 904*                               x
1128          MasterCard Deposit             15.97
```

x for 7804 should equal 70.47

x for 904 should equal 15.96

Comment: You should try sumif() - will do that nicely...

Comment: Both `sumif()` and pivot tables will work in this case

Answer (score 2):

So, as per comment, but I have consolidated the data:

```
SUMIF(A$1:A$8,D2,$B$1:$B$8)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into pivot tables. You can do a number of different summarization tasks with them. Here's a screenshot of what you're looking for done with a pivot table. I did need to add a column with a unique value for each row so that it would still show all the rows instead of just summary data.

[image]